# Ignoring folders when organizing files

Tags: python, organization

I am fairly new to python, and trying to write a program that organizes files based on their extensions

```
import os
import shutil

newpath1 = r'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Downloads\Images'
if not os.path.exists(newpath1):                     # check to see if they already exist
    os.makedirs(newpath1)
newpath2 = r'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Downloads\Documents'
if not os.path.exists(newpath2):
    os.makedirs(newpath2)
newpath3 = r'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Downloads\Else'
if not os.path.exists(newpath3):
    os.makedirs(newpath3)

source_folder = r"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Downloads" # the location of the files we want to move
files = os.listdir(source_folder)

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(('.JPG', '.png', '.jpg')):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_folder,file), os.path.join(newpath1,file))
    elif file.endswith(('.pdf', '.pptx')):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_folder,file), os.path.join(newpath2,file))
    #elif file is folder:
        #do nothing
    else:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_folder,file), os.path.join(newpath3,file))
```

I want it to move **files** based on their extensions. However, I am trying to figure out how to stop the **folders** from moving. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, for some reason, not every file is being moved, even though they have the same extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/5763413)

In particular, the `os.walk` [command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/os-walk-python/). This command returns a 3-tuple with the dirpath, dirname, and filename.

In your case, you should use `[x[0] for x in os.walk(dirname)]`

Answer (score 1):

As with most path operations, I recommend using the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module. Pathlib is available since Python 3.4 and has portable (multi platform), high-level API for file system operations.

I recommend using the following methods on `Path` objects, to determine their type:

- [Path.is_file()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file)
- [Path.is_dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir)

```py
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


# Using class for nicer grouping of target directories
# Note that pathlib.Path enables Unix-like path construction, even on Windows
class TargetPaths:
    IMAGES = Path.home().joinpath("Documents/Downloads/Images")
    DOCUMENTS = Path.home().joinpath("Documents/Downloads/Documents")
    OTHER = Path.home().joinpath("Documents/Downloads/Else")
    __ALL__ = (IMAGES, DOCUMENTS, OTHER)


for target_dir in TargetPaths.__ALL__:
    if not target_dir.is_dir():
        target_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)


source_folder = Path.home().joinpath("Documents/Downloads")  # the location of the files we want to move
# Get absolute paths to the files in source_folder
# files is a generator (only usable once)
files = (path.absolute() for path in source_folder.iterdir() if path.is_file())


def move(source_path, target_dir):
    shutil.move(str(source_path), str(target_dir.joinpath(file.name))


for path in files:
    if path.suffix in ('.JPG', '.png', '.jpg'):
        move(path, TargetPaths.IMAGES)
    elif path.suffix in ('.pdf', '.pptx'):
        move(path, TargetPaths.DOCUMENTS)
    else:
        move(path, TargetPaths.OTHER)
```